# SQL Rank New Rows Higher But Only Max Every 4 Rows, Use Default Order By Otherwise

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

The problem is seemingly straight forward, but after messing with RANK, Partition, etc. I have not been able to find a viable solution.

We have a simple table of auction items and each has a search score. We want to give newly listed auction items a boost and show them every 4th result, even if their search score is lower. The newly listed items themselves rank by the search score (realize it's possible for a newly listed item to get slightly demoted if it has a high search score).

Sample data for auction items:

| id | Name | is_new | search score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | Apple iPad | false | 200 |
| 3 | Samsung s8 | false | 190 |
| 12 | Another item | false | 181 |
| 412 | ps4 | true | 10 |
| 33 | yet another | false | 177 |
| 201 | watch | false | 173 |
| 112 | iphone x | false | 169 |
| 450 | video game | true | 6 |
| 12 | auction item | false | 165 |

The problem we're trying to solve is giving new items a boost, but not having them cluster together. So in the above results, each is_new = true item is displayed every 4th row, sorted themselves by search score.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added some sample data with desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use an arithmetic trick.  I think this does it:

```
order by (case when is_new = 'false'
               then row_number() over (partition by is_new order by score desc) * 1.0
               else row_number() over (partition by is_new order by is_new score desc) * 3 + 0.5
          end)
```

This inserts the `is_new = 'true'` records as every fourth row.